# How to define an interface throwing a generic exception type?

Tags: java, generics, exception, interface, throws

I wanna define an interface, like

```
public interface Visitor <ArgType, ResultType, SelfDefinedException> {
     public ResultType visitProgram(Program prog, ArgType arg) throws SelfDefinedException;
     //...
}
```

during implementation, selfDefinedException varies. (selfDefinedException as a generic undefined for now)
  Is there a way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: You could have your interface be defined to throw an exception that is the superclass of all the selfDefinedExceptions.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You just need to constrain the exception type to be suitable to be thrown. For example:

```
interface Visitor<ArgType, ResultType, ExceptionType extends Throwable> {
    ResultType visitProgram(String prog, ArgType arg) throws ExceptionType;
}
```

Or perhaps:

```
interface Visitor<ArgType, ResultType, ExceptionType extends Exception> {
    ResultType visitProgram(String prog, ArgType arg) throws ExceptionType;
}
```

Comment: But you'd want to use a conventional naming convention, right?

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline: Yes, although the convention in Java for naming type parameters isn't as clear as it is in .NET...

Comment: @JonSkeet I think there are quite clear: single upper case letter (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html) But it isn't really satisfying so we don't want to follow them :-)

Answer (score 6):

Your genericized parameter would need to extend Throwable. Something like this:

```
public class Weird<K, V, E extends Throwable> {

   public void someMethod(K k, V v) throws E {
      return;
   }
}
```

Comment: It's a kind of shame that `E` can't be a set of exception types.

Comment: Indeed, that would be a variadic type parameter, which still does not seem to be supported.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like

```
public interface Test<T extends Throwable> {
    void test() throws T;
}
```

And then, for example

```
public class TestClass implements Test<RuntimeException> {
    @Override
    public void test() throws RuntimeException {
    }
}
```

Of course, when you instantiate the class you have to declare the exception that is thrown.

EDIT: Of course, replace `Throwable` with any of your self defined exceptions that will extend `Throwable`, `Exception` or similar.

Answer (score -4):

If I understand the question, you can throw

```
Exception
```

as it is the parent class.